# Generating thumbnails of the webpages visited on a client side

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, client-side, thumbnails

I developing an extension - firefox so with this extension i keep track of the pages the user visits and now what i want to do is, i want to be able to popup a thumbnail of the webpage when the user hovers the mouse over the link. i have done that using third party websites for generating thumbnials such as **http://images.websnapr.com**. I was wondering if there was anyway i could do it on clientside without having to use third party website.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use firefox's own canvas. Look here for an example :

http://fixunix.com/mozilla/408090-firefox-page-capture-image-need-minor-tweaks-autochosen.html

Comment: Hi a bit late but is there a good tutorial on firefox canvas? I ahve never used canvas so looks like i will have to start from the begining?
Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest starting with mozilla's own :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to look at the screengrab extension, which does just that:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146

(i think it uses java as underlying layer)